# Can an iframe content be rendered in Quirks mode when the parent is rendered in Standards mode?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, meta-tags, quirks-mode

I have an html page which looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>

<body>

  This is parent frame
  <input type="button" value="click" onclick="test()"/>

  <iframe src="child.html">
  </iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="parent.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

And a child page who content is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=5">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is Chiild frame
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="test()"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="child.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have opened the parent page in IE9.
Even though I have included meta tag with content as IE=5 in child, the document mode in child is still in IE9.

There is scenario where I need to open the child in Quirks mode and I cannot remove the meta tag in Parent page.

Is there any way to render the child in quirks mode or IE5 mode, when the parent is in standards mode.